Issue with React IpAddressInput Component: Deleting a digit affects other segments unexpectedly
I've implemented a custom IpAddressInput text box component in React using react-text-mask for input masking and validation of IPv4 addresses. The component allows users to input all IPv4 address segmented by dots (e.g., 123.456.789.222,92.168.0.1, 10.0.0.1, 172.16.254.1, 255.255.255.0, 127.0.0.1).
The main issue I'm encountering is that when I attempt to delete a digit from one segment of the IP address, it sometimes deletes digits from other segments as well, resulting in unexpected behavior. For example, if I try to delete the digit 5 from 123.456.789.222, it might incorrectly update to 123.467.892.22_. and its not give correct ipv4 format after editing and click outside of the text box.
Expected Behavior:
I expect the IpAddressInput component to allow editing and deleting digits in each segment of the IP address independently, without affecting other segments. For example, deleting a digit from one segment **123.456.789.222 **to  123.4_6.78.2_2, after clicking outside of the text box i need to get formatted ip in text box like  **123.46.78.22
**
Actual Behavior:
When attempting to delete a digit from one segment, such as 5 from 123.456.789.222, it sometimes causes digits to be deleted from other segments as well (123.467.892.22_), which is unexpected and incorrect.Not formatting after clicking outside of the text box
My IpAddressInput text box component code is below.Any insights or suggestions on how to correct this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import MaskedInput from 'react-text-mask';

       const IpAddressInput = ({ initialValue = '', onChange }) => {
    const [ value, setValue ] = useState(initialValue);

    const handleTextBoxChange = (event) => {
        const { value: newValue } = event.target;

        // Validate the entered IP address
        const isValidIP = validateIP(newValue);

        if (isValidIP) {
            setValue(newValue); // Update state with the formatted value
            onChange(newValue); // Notify parent of value change
        }
        // If not valid, do not update the state or notify parent
    };

    const validateIP = (ip) => {
        // Basic IPv4 validation
        const segments = ip.split('.');
        if (segments.length !== 4) return false;
        for (let segment of segments) {
            if (!/^\d+$/.test(segment)) return false; // Must be numeric
            const num = parseInt(segment, 10);
            if (num < 0 || num > 255) return false; // Must be in range 0-255
        }
        return true;
    };

    useEffect(
        () => {
            // Initialize the value
            setValue(initialValue);
        },
        [ initialValue ]
    );

    return (
        <MaskedInput
            mask={[ /\d/, /\d?/, /\d?/, '.', /\d/, /\d?/, /\d?/, '.', /\d/, /\d?/,        /\d?/, '.', /\d/, /\d?/, /\d?/ ]}
            value={value}
            onChange={handleTextBoxChange}
            placeholder="Enter IPv4 address"
            keepCharPositions={false} // Disable keepCharPositions to prevent deletion         issue
        />
    );
      };

     export default IpAddressInput;





//calling this in parent

   
     function Settings() {
    const [ ipAddress, setIpAddress ] = useState('');

    const handleIpAddressChange = (value) => {
        
        console.log('IP Address changed:', value);
        setIpAddress(value);
    };
    return (
        
            <ControlContainer>
                <Typography variant="h7" mb={13}>
                    IP Address
                </Typography>
                <IpAddressInput initialValue={ipAddress} onChange=   {handleIpAddressChange} />
            </ControlContainer>
            
    );
       }

       export default Settings;



Can you clarify the comment on why you set keepCharPositions to false? 123.456.789.222 -> 123.467.892.22_ seems to be the documented behaviour for keepCharPositions=false

Oops! I made a mistake while trying different code. The positioning is working, but I'm still struggling to get the format right after clicking outside. Any ideas?

means deleting a digit from one segment 123.456.789.222 to 123.4_6.78.2_2, after clicking outside of the text box i need to get formatted ip in text box like 123.46.78.22
